# The validity of the potential function for splay tree

Tags: algorithms, data-structures, amortized-analysis, binary-search-trees, splay-trees

The paper ["Self-Adjusting Binary Search Trees"](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~sleator/papers/self-adjusting.pdf) defines (Page 658) the potential function for analyzing the amortized cost of a sequence of $m$ splay operations as the sum of the ranks of all nodes in the splay tree, where the rank of a node $x$ is taken as the logarithm of the size ($s(x)$; i.e., number of nodes in) of the subtree rooted at $x$:

$$\Phi(T_i) = \sum_{x \in T} \log (s(x)).$$

To make sure that the amortized cost is an upper bound of the actual cost, it is required that the final potential is no less than the initial potential $\Phi(T_0)$ (Page 657):

$$\forall 1 \le i \le m: \Phi(T_i) \ge \Phi(T_0).$$

***Problem:*** How to verify the condition above? (I did not find the argument in the paper.) Maybe it is not necessary to verify this condition; if so, why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Answer My Own Question:***

***The short answer:***

We don't have to verify $$\forall 1 \le i \le m: \Phi(T_i) \ge \Phi(T_0).$$ This condition is a special case of a more general one, which we need to verify for this example.

***The detailed answer:***

Consider a data structure $D$ and its states $D_0 \cdots D_m$ produced by a sequence of $m$ operations $o_1 \cdots o_m$:
$$
D_0,\; o_1,\; D_1,\; o_2,\; \cdots,\; \underbrace{D_{i-1},\; o_{i},\; D_{i}}_{\text{the $i$-th operation}},\; \cdots,\; D_{m-1},\; o_{m},\; D_{m}.
$$

The amortized cost of the $i$-th operation $o_i$ is defined as:
$$\hat{c_i} = c_i + \Big(\Phi(D_{i}) - \Phi(D_{i-1})\Big)$$

Therefore, the total actual cost of these $m$ operations equals the total amortized cost plus the net decrease in potential from the initial to the final state.

$$
\sum_{1 \le i \le m} c_i = \left( \sum_{1 \le i \le m} \hat{c_i} \right) 
 + \Big(\underbrace{\Phi(D_{0}) - \Phi(D_m)}_{\text{net decrease in potential}} \Big).
$$

For each upper bound $\Box$ for $\Phi(D_{0}) - \Phi(D_m)$, we get a corresponding upper bound for the total actual cost of all operations:

$$
\sum_{1 \le i \le m} c_i \le \left( \sum_{1 \le i \le m} \hat{c_i} \right) + \Box.
$$

The condition $$\forall 1 \le i \le m: \Phi(D_i) \ge \Phi(D_0)$$ in the post is just a special case of deriving upper bounds for the total actual cost, where the upper bound is the total amortized cost. Moreover, it is common to choose $\Phi$ such that $\Phi(D_0) = 0$ and $\Phi(D_i) \ge 0$ for all $i$.

To verify the validity of the potential function for splay trees, we use the following upper bound for $\Phi(T_{0}) - \Phi(T_i)$:

$$\Phi(T_{0}) - \Phi(T_i) \le n \log n.$$